# Can I migrate from IPN to webhooks for existing Paypal subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-ipn

I am working on a website which was created a few years back, where users have been subscribing via Paypal. This is a Wordpress website with the subscription part handled by a plugin; the plugin uses Paypal's old API as well as IPN to receive notifications from Paypal and do things like renewing existing subscriptions.

I would like to migrate from IPN to webhooks, but is it possible to receive webhook notifications for existing subscriptions? What are my options here? Please note that there are no apps created in the Paypal developer dashboard, so I have no client id or such credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Live Applications](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live) dashboard, scroll to the bottom and under NVP/SOAP Webhooks click Manage Webhooks and Add Webhook at the bottom. Use a service like e.g. http://webhooks.site/ if you don't have a listener of your own available.

Then see if you receive any events for your existing subscriptions. From what I have heard **the answer is no**, but the only way to be sure is to try it.

What I do know is these backported "NVP/SOAP" webhooks are live-only and cannot be tested in sandbox (unlike most PayPal features)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, although perhaps the best thing to do is to create an IPN listener for existing subscriptions and a webhook listener for new ones. However just today I've read in the dashboard that the IPN simulator will be discontinued next 8 December: do you know if only the simulator will be discontinued or are there maybe plans to shut IPN off completely?

Comment: Only the simulator, as IPN should not be used for any new integrations

Comment: I can confirm that **the answer is no**. I have an old wordpress website that uses IPN. I have a new website that uses the REST API and webhooks. I'm not getting any webhook messages from old subscriptions. But I am getting messages from new subscriptions. So, now I have to support IPN until the end of time?